# Rotating sprite with a center of rotation in SDL2

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, image-rotation

I want to rotate a sprite in C and SDL2, with a set center of rotation, and without scaling or anti-aliasing.

My game resolution is 320x240, and the display is scaled up when I set the game to full screen, because I'm using [`SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, 320, 240)`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize).

1. Using SDL2's [`SDL_RenderCopyEx()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx) (or [`SDL_RenderCopyExF()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyExF)) to rotate a SDL_Texture.

   As shown in this example ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4FQ3.jpg ) when the window is set to full screen, the texture is scaled up and at much higher resolution. Is would like the final 320x240 rendering to be scaled up, not the individual textures.
2. Using SDL_gfx's [`rotozoomSurface()`](https://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL2_gfx/Docs/html/_s_d_l2__rotozoom_8h.html#a6f5f31a362f63370dc60049df14d6856) was a possible alternative.

   However, as shown in this example ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX08f.jpg ), while this method give the intended low-resolution and aliased look, it has no center of rotation, and renders the transparency color as half-transparent black.

Is there a function that does what I'm looking for? Are there some tricks to get around that?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but you may try `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0");` before creating the textures.

Comment: Not sure i got your problem right, you want your rendered screen to be 320x240 and then upscaled to fullscreen with... what scaling method? Bilinear? Nearest/no filtering? Something else? You can create render texture of required size and render everything into it.

Comment: @keltar The scaling method I would like to use is nearest neighbor (no filtering).

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to render what you want to in a `SDL_Texture`, and then print this texture into the renderer, using something like :

```c
    // Set 'your_texture' as target
SDL_SetRenderTarget(your_renderer, your_texture);

    // We are now printing the rotated image on the texture
SDL_RenderCopyEx(your_renderer, // we still use the renderer; it will be automatically printed into the texture 'your_texture'
                   your_image,
                   &srcrect,
                   &dstrect,
                   angle,
                   &center,
                   SDL_FLIP_NONE); // unless you want to flip vertically / horizontally

    // Set the renderer as target and print the previous texture
SDL_SetRenderTarget(your_renderer, NULL);
SDL_RenderClear(your_renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy (your_renderer, your_texture, NULL, NULL); // here the scale is automatically done
SDL_RenderPresent(your_renderer);
```

It works, but I don't know if it is very efficient.
Don't forget to define `your_texture` with a [SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TextureAccess) access.

Hope this helps,
Durza42

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Durza42, here's the solution to my problem:

```
#define kScreenWidth 320
#define kScreenHeight 240

SDL_Window* g_window = NULL;
SDL_Texture* g_texture = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* g_renderer = NULL;

SDL_Texture* g_sprite = NULL;
double g_sprite_angle = 0.0;
SDL_FRect g_sprite_frect = {
  .x = 50.0f,
  .y = 50.0f,
  .w = 32.0f,
  .h = 32.0f,
};

void
sdl_load(void)
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  g_window = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight, 0);
  g_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(g_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
  g_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight);
  SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(g_renderer, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight);
}

void
sprite_load(void)
{
  g_sprite = IMG_LoadTexture(g_renderer, "./sprite.png");
}

void
draw(void)
{
  SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, g_texture);
  SDL_RenderClear(g_renderer);
  SDL_RenderCopyExF(g_renderer, g_sprite, NULL, &g_sprite_frect, g_sprite_angle, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);

  SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, NULL);
  SDL_RenderClear(g_renderer);
  SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_texture, NULL, NULL);
  
  SDL_RenderPresent(g_renderer);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).